# How do I add a UISlider to a SKScene that isn't the main scene of the View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit, uislider

I'm creating a Sprite Kit game with one view controller and multiple skscenes. Basically, the application loads the view controller, which loads the menu scene, and then I use SKTransitions to go between scenes. In creating a settings scene, I would like to be able to use certain UIKit elements like a UISlider - however, I can only ever get the UISlider to show up on the menu scene. What exactly do I need to do in order to get the UISlider to show up only on the settings scene? Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: I would recommend making your own slider control, it is not worth the hassle of combining UIKit with SceneKit,  and a slider control is not hard to do (Look at SKCropNode to start it off)

Comment: I agree. Make a custom UISlider class. SpriteKit doesn't have any buttons but I created my own called JKButtonNode and it's a subclass of SKSpriteNode and it works almost exactly like a UIButton. It's really easy to implement in any SprteKit game.

Answer (score 2):

As Knight of dragon said its best to avoid using UIKit in SpriteKit as much as possible.

However in some cases UIKit is very useful in SpriteKit. For example I use UICollectionViews to show my World and Level select menu in one of my games because its the nicest option (cell reuse, dequeueing, animation effects etc).

Just use the view property of a SKScene to add UIKit elements in a specific scene.

```
class MenuScene: SKScene {

     let slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 250, width: 280, height: 20))

     override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
         loadSlider()
     }

     private func loadSlider() {
         ...
         view?.addSubview(slider) // if you are calling view outside of DidMoveToView it is an optional, so use ?
     }
}
```

Dont forget to remove it again when you change scene as its added to your GameViewController.

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
     slider.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Hope this helps.